# Android Anko seekbar skinning

Tags: android, kotlin, dsl, anko

I have a SeekBar in my anko dsl (i use 0.10.4) layout like this

```
seekBar {
                max = 2
                progress = 1
                progressDrawable = drawable(R.drawable.seek_bar_progress)
                thumb = drawable(R.drawable.seek_bar_thumb)
                onSeekBarChangeListener {
                    onProgressChanged { _, progress, _ ->
                        // Something
                    }
                }
            }.lparams(matchParent) {
                setMargins(dip(16), dip(8), dip(16), dip(8))
            }
```

**seek_bar_progress.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#D9D9D9"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorRed"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

**seek_bar_thumb.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorRed"/>
        <size android:height="26dp" android:width="26dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

and i have ugly view with this settings on any android devices
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPpyu.png).

But when i use "include" tag i have a correct seekbar implementation [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piE5V.png)

```
include<SeekBar>(R.layout.seek_lay) {
                progress = 1
                onSeekBarChangeListener {
                    onProgressChanged { _, progress, _ ->
                        // Something
                    }
                }
            }.lparams(matchParent) {
                setMargins(dip(16), dip(8), dip(16), dip(8))
            }
```

**seek_lay.xml**

```
<SeekBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:max="2"
android:maxHeight="2dp"
android:minHeight="2dp"
android:progress="1"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress"
android:thumb="@drawable/seek_bar_thumb"
/>
```

does anybody faces with the same problem? And how i can resolve this if it's possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the same problem today.. And I search for hours to solve this problem too, but I could not find any 'normally' solution at all.

Finally I change the field ***mMaxHeight*** with java reflection to achieve the result.

Just notice that ***mMaxHeight*** belong to **ProgressBar.class**, so you need to use **ProgressBar.class** to find it.

```
val field = ProgressBar::class.java.getDeclaredField("mMaxHeight")
val accessible = field.isAccessible
field.isAccessible = true
field.setInt(seekBar, [value])
field.isAccessible = accessible
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLc0U.png)

I dont know it is a good or bad way, it just can work for me.

Comment: thank for your answer. it's working too, but i find a better solution to use with anko. i use "include" tag for custom xml layout like seekbar
seekBar = include<SeekBar>(R.layout.seek_lay) {} 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeekBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxHeight="2dp"
    android:minHeight="2dp"
    android:progress="1"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_bar_thumb"
    />

Comment: yes, using xml is straightforward. I thought you originally wanted to done without xml :)

Comment: BTW, **android:minHeight** & **android:maxHeight** can be used in xml because they're defined in [ProgreesBar's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java) styleable, and they do not have setter that we cannot change it programmatically